# How to pass uri in android compose navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I try pass uri with android compose navigation. In ome screnn I receve uri of file and I need to pass it to next screen for processing.

```
navigation(
        startDestination = NavigationItem.ProfileNavigationItem.route,
        route = PROFILE_ROOT_ROUT
    ) { 
       composable(route = NavigationItem.ChooseSendProfileNavigation.route,
            arguments = listOf(navArgument("uri") {
                type =  // WHAT TYPE TO USE FOR URI?
            })

        ) {

            val uri =  //WHAT TYPE TO USE FOR URI?

            ProfileChooseRestoreScreen(uri!!, navHostController, paddingValues)
        }
    }
```

What type to use for uri?

I tried to pass the uri as a string but it doesn't work

Comment: You can convert it to String.

Comment: you don't need a type, just `nullable: Boolean` and `defaultValue`, you can see some [examples](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/make-it-so-android/blob/main/final/app/src/main/java/com/example/makeitso/MakeItSoApp.kt)